# VHDL Synthesis, can`t make code be synthesizable

Tags: encryption, vhdl

I have some code on VHDL language, this code male some encryption/decryption operation. Help me please make this code be synthesizable because Xilinx IDE told me that

> line 82: Operator  must have constant modulo operand.
>   This is my code. Maybe you have some wish for me how I can refactor it.

```
library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.STD_LOGIC_TEXTIO.all;
    use ieee.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;
    use ieee.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED.all;
    use ieee.NUMERIC_STD.all;
    use ieee.NUMERIC_BIT.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
    use ieee.MATH_REAL.all;
    use ieee.MATH_COMPLEX.all;

entity comp is
  port(
   clk : in STD_LOGIC;
     word : in INTEGER;
     n : inout INTEGER;
   v1 : out INTEGER;
   v2 : out INTEGER;
   v3 : out INTEGER;
   v4 : out INTEGER;
   v5 : out INTEGER;
   v6 : out INTEGER;
   v7 : out INTEGER;
   v8 : out INTEGER
  );
end comp;

architecture arch of comp is

---- Signal declarations used on the diagram ----

signal g1 : INTEGER := 1;
signal g2 : INTEGER := 1;
signal g3 : INTEGER := 1;
signal k1 : INTEGER := 0;
signal k2 : INTEGER := 0;
signal k3 : INTEGER := 0;
signal m1 : INTEGER;
signal m2 : INTEGER;
signal m3 : INTEGER;
---signal n : INTEGER;
signal p1 : INTEGER;
signal p1_g1 : INTEGER;
signal p2 : INTEGER;
signal p2_g2 : INTEGER;
signal p3 : INTEGER;
signal p3_g3 : INTEGER;
signal sqrt1 : INTEGER;
signal sqrt2 : INTEGER;
signal sqrt3 : INTEGER;
signal w : INTEGER;
---signal word : INTEGER;   

begin

---- Processes ----

read : process (clk)
                   begin
                     if clk'event and clk = '1' then
                        n <= p1 * p2 * p3;
                        w <= word * word MOD n;

                        sqrt1 <= w MOD p1;
                        sqrt2 <= w MOD p2;
                        sqrt3 <= w MOD p3;

                        if k1*k1 MOD p1 /= sqrt1 then
                            k1 <= k1 + 1;
                        else 
                            g1 <= k1; 
                            end if;

                        if k2*k2 MOD p2 /= sqrt2 then
                            k2 <= k2 + 1;
                        else 
                            g2 <= k2; 
                        end if;

                        if k3*k3 MOD p3 /= sqrt3 then
                            k3 <= k3 + 1;
                        else 
                             g3 <= k3;
                        end if;

                        p1_g1 <= p1 - g1;
                        p2_g2 <= p2 - g2;
                        p3_g3 <= p3 - g3;
                        m1 <= n / p1;
                        m2 <= n / p2;
                        m3 <= n / p3;
                        v1 <= (-m1 * g1 + m2 * g2 + m3 * g3) MOD n;
                        v2 <= (-m1 * g1 + m2 * g2 + m3 * p3_g3) MOD n;
                        v3 <= (-m1 * g1 + m2 * p2_g2 + m3 * g3) MOD n;
                        v4 <= (-m1 * g1 + m2 * p2_g2 + m3 * p3_g3) MOD n;
                        v5 <= (-m1 * p1_g1 + m2 * g2 + m3 * g3) MOD n;
                        v6 <= (-m1 * p1_g1 + m2 * g2 + m3 * p3_g3) MOD n;
                        v7 <= (-m1 * p1_g1 + m2 * p2_g2 + m3 * g3) MOD n;
                        v8 <= (-m1 * p1_g1 + m2 * p2_g2 + m3 * p3_g3) MOD n;
                     end if;
                   end process;        
end arch;
```

Comment: Delete most of those library USE clauses for a start! Keep `std_logic_1164` and `numeric_std`. Then, any time you have code of the form `w MOD p1;` synthesis will only accept it if `p1` is a `constant` (not a `signal`. (also, `n` is an output not an inout)

Comment: ISE or Vivado? Under ISE the XST reference, section XST Language Support, VHDL Operators table mod "Supported if the right operand is a constant power of 2". UG901, VHDL Support VHDL Constructs and Support Status table mod says the same.

Answer (score 0):

In VHDL/verilog MOD ,REM and DIVISION operators are not synthesizable. Division is only possible when the second operand is a power of 2.
even if you want to traverse your code using a loop to find the remainder you need to put a constant in the condition segment to get your code synthesized.

Comment: This is untrue. These operators are synthesisable in some tools when the divisor is a constant; not necessarily a power of 2. You may not always like the result, but that's another matter.